# JavaScript- Create an empty json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have to create an empty array with the following keys: "id", "action".
How do I create it?

Comment: `var a = {id: null, action: null};` Also, you cannot create an array with keys. It's an object, which you then can place into an array.

Comment: Arrays don't have keys. And are you sure you want to create JSON, and not just a plain array or object? All in all I think you are better off reading a JavaScript tutorial, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @vinayakj: fair enough (I simply considered keys to be different from indexes for this example). But obviously arrays don't have the type of key the OP seems to want to have.

Comment: @vinayakj: http://www.internetslang.com/OP-meaning-definition.asp

Comment: @vinayakj: I could, but pasting a link is easier on a tablet :P

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://$SITEURL$/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming to be placed in a variable, because you have 'json' tagged.
The following is some explanation of each step of a simple example breakdown:

```
// create an empty array
var array = [];

// create an object with properties "id", "action" with mock values
var object = {
  id: "1",
  action: "shout" 
}

// add object to array
array.push(object);

// create encode json string
var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thankss !! it's works

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
JSON.stringify({
    id: null,
    action: null
})
```

Comment: @Joriktos- for what the stringify?

Comment: To get JSON-data?
This would be the output:
"{"id":null,"action":null}"

Comment: @saritrotshild: you wanted JSON, didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is pure JSON example with sample data that should give you guidance

```
{
  "object": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "action": "New"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "action": "Open"
    },
    {
      "Id": "3",
      "action": "Close"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how does that creates an array?

Comment: check question edits, question changed...